# Can't see (imported) configurable products in catalog or search

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, import-products

I may need help...
If I manually create a configurable product I see it fine in the frontend.

However when I import products from stock with my homemade script, they don't show up.
On my backend all seems fine and the product is just right, even associated products are correctly addressed.
The associated simple products are fine too, when I set them to be visible they are ok and I can see them in the catalog and work fine.

My (LONG VERSION) import script (don't judge me for bad programming pratice pls):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
if (! isset($_POST))
    exit();

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$context = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context');
$attributeRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface');
$tableFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\TableFactory');
$attributeOptionManagement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface');
$optionLabelFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterfaceFactory');
$optionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$associatedIdMap = new stdClass();
$nameSkuMap = new stdClass();
$attributGustoMap = new stdClass();
$attributeValues;


function getAttribute($attributeCode)

{
    global $attributeRepository;
    return $attributeRepository->get($attributeCode);
}

function createOrGetId($attributeCode, $label)
{
    if (strlen($label) < 1) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Label for %1 must not be empty.', $attributeCode));
    }
    global $attributGustoMap;
    global $optionLabelFactory;
    global $optionFactory;
    global $attributeOptionManagement;
    // Does it already exist?
    $optionId = getOptionId($attributeCode, $label);

    if (! $optionId) {
        // If no, add it.
        $optionLabel = $optionLabelFactory->create();
        $optionLabel->setStoreId(0);
        $optionLabel->setLabel($label);

        $option = $optionFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($label);
        $option->setStoreLabels([
            $optionLabel
        ]);
        $option->setSortOrder(0);
        $option->setIsDefault(false);

        $attrId = getAttribute($attributeCode)->getAttributeId();

        $attributeOptionManagement->add(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, '157', $option);

        // Get the inserted ID. Should be returned from the installer, but it isn't.
        $optionId = getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, true);
        $attributGustoMap->$label = $optionId;
    }

    return $optionId;
}

function getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, $force = false)
{
    global $attributGustoMap, $attributeValues;

    if (property_exists($attributGustoMap, $label)) {
        return $attributGustoMap->$label;
    }
    $attribute = getAttribute($attributeCode);

    global $tableFactory;

    // Build option array if necessary
    if ($force === true || ! isset($attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()])) {

        $attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()] = [];

        // We have to generate a new sourceModel instance each time through to prevent it from
        // referencing its _options cache. No other way to get it to pick up newly-added values.

        $sourceModel = $tableFactory->create();
        $sourceModel->setAttribute($attribute);

        foreach ($sourceModel->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$option['label']] = $option['value'];
        }
    }

    // Return option ID if exists
    if (isset($attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$label])) {
        return $attributeValues[$attribute->getAttributeId()][$label];
    }

    // Return false if does not exist
    return false;
}

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (isset($name) and ! empty($name)) {
    $location = './';
    if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location . $name)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($name, null, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

        $deletedProductList = $xml->DeletedProducts->Product;
        $updateProductsList = $xml->UpdatedProducts->Product;
        $product;

        if (is_object($updateProductsList)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($updateProductsList); $i ++) {
                $desc = $updateProductsList[$i]->Description;
                $code = (string) $updateProductsList[$i]->Code;
                $price = (float) $updateProductsList[$i]->GrossPrice1;
                $brand = (string) $updateProductsList[$i]->ProducerName;
                $qty = (int) $updateProductsList[$i]->AvailableQty;
                try {
                    $product = $productRepository->get($code);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
                }
                $product->setSku($code);
                $product->setPrice($price);
                $product->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, // 'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability
                    'qty' => $qty // qty
                ));
                $notes = (string) $updateProductsList[$i]->Notes;
                $scadenza = false;
                if (str_contains($notes, "--scadenza:")) {

                    $scadenza = explode("--scadenza:", $notes)[1];
                    $scadenza = trim($scadenza);
                    $scadenzaArray = explode("/", $scadenza);
                    if (count($scadenzaArray) == 3) {

                        $scadenza = $scadenzaArray[1] . '/' . $scadenzaArray[0] . '/' . $scadenzaArray[2];
                        $product->setCustomAttribute('scadenza', $scadenza);
                    }
                }
                
                //BRANDO MIO
                $existsbrand = GetBrandIdFromName($brand);
                if(!$existsbrand) {
                    $brid = createBrand($brand);
                } else {
                    $brid = $existsbrand;
                }
                
                if($hasbrand = HasBrand($product->getId())) {
                    $newbr = UpdateProdBrand($product->getId(), $brid);
                }
                else {
                    $newbr = NewProdBrand($product->getId(), $brid);
                }
                /////////

                if (! str_contains($desc, '--')) {
                    // simple
                    $product->setName($desc);
                    upsertProduct($product, 'simple');
                } else {
                    $prodName = explode('--', $desc)[0];
                    if (str_contains($desc, 'BASE')) {
                        // configurable
                        $product->setName($prodName);
                        $product = upsertProduct($product, 'configurable');
                        $nameSkuMap->$prodName = $code;
                    } else if (str_contains($desc, 'gusto:')) {
                        // associated
                        $product->setName($prodName);
                        $gustoAttrCode = $product->getResource()
                                         ->getAttribute("gusto")
                                         ->getAttributeCode();
                        $gustoId = createOrGetId($gustoAttrCode, trim(strtolower(explode('--gusto:', $desc)[1])));
                        $product->setGusto($gustoId);

                        $product = upsertProduct($product, 'simple', 1); 
                        $productId = $product->getId();
                        if (property_exists($associatedIdMap, $prodName)) {
                            $associatedIdArray = $associatedIdMap->$prodName;
                            array_push($associatedIdArray, $productId);
                        } else {
                            $associatedIdArray = array(
                                $productId
                            );
                        }
                        $associatedIdMap->$prodName = $associatedIdArray;
                    } else {
                        echo "unknown product type - " . $code . "\n";
                        // unknown
                    }
                }
                

            }
        }
        foreach ($associatedIdMap as $productName => $prodAssocIds) {
            if (property_exists($nameSkuMap, $productName)) {
                updateAssociatedIds($nameSkuMap->$productName, $prodAssocIds);
            } else {
                echo "no base product - " . $productName . "\n";
            }
        }
        if (is_object($deletedProductList)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($deletedProductList); $i ++) {
                $code = $deletedProductList[$i]->Code;
                try {
                    $product = $productRepository->get($code);
                    $productRepository->delete($product);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Cannot Delete - sku not exists - " . $code . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo 'not uploaded';
    }
} else {
    echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
}

////////////////////////////
function updateAssociatedIds($code, $productIds)
{
    global $productRepository;
    $product = $productRepository->get($code);
    $product_resource = $product->getResource();
    $gusto_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('gusto');
    $gusto_attribute_id = $gusto_attribute->getId();
    $configurable_attributes = array(
        'gusto'
    );
    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(
        $gusto_attribute_id
    ), $product);

    $configurable_attributes_data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurable_attributes_data);

    $product->setAssociatedProductIds($productIds);

    $product->save();
}

////////////////////////////
function upsertProduct($product, $type, $visibility = 4)
{
    $product->setTypeId($type)
        ->setStatus(1)
        ->
    // 1 = enabled, 2 = disabled
    setAttributeSetId(4)
        ->
    // 4 = default
    setTaxClassId(2)
        ->
    // 0 = None, 2 = Default product tax class
    setCategoryIds(array(
        2
    ))
        ->
    // 2 = Default category
    setWebsiteIds(array(
        1
    ))
        ->
    // 1 = Default Website ID
    setStoreId(0)
        ->setUrlKey($product->getSku())
        ->
    // 0 = Default store ID
    setVisibility($visibility); // 4 = Catalog & Search

    $product->save();

    return $product;
}

//////////////////
function GetBrandIdFromName($brname) {
    $servername = "SERVER";
    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PW";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT brand_id FROM magento.tm_brand WHERE name = ?");
    $param = "$brname";
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($brid);
    $rez = null;
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $rez = $brid;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $rez;
}

//////////////////
function createBrand($brname) {
    $urlkey = str_replace(" ", "-", $brname);
    $urlkey = str_replace("\"", "", $urlkey);
    $urlkey = str_replace("'", "", $urlkey);
    $urlkey = strtolower($urlkey);
    
    $servername = "SERVER";
    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PW";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO magento.tm_brand (name, status, url_key, title, website_id) VALUES (?, 1, ?, ?, 1)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $brname, $urlkey, $brname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rinsid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $rinsid;
}


//////////////////
function HasBrand($prid) {
    $servername = "SERVER";
    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PW";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT value FROM magento.catalog_product_entity_int  where attribute_id = 150 AND entity_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $prid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($bid);
    $rez = null;
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $rez = $bid;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $rez;
}

//////////////////////////
function UpdateProdBrand($prid, $brid) {
    $servername = "SERVER";
    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PW";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE magento.catalog_product_entity_int SET value = ? WHERE entity_id = ?; ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $brid, $prid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rr = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $rr;
}

////////////////////////////
function NewProdBrand($prid, $brid) {
    $servername = "SERVER";
    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PW";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO magento.catalog_product_entity_int (attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (150, 0, ?, ?); ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $prid, $brid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rr = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    return $rr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your configurable product, there is an attribute with name Visibility. You need to set it to Catalog, Search. This would make your product visible in search.